# How do I open a .jtd file with OpenOffice?

Tags: openoffice-writer

I can't figure out how to open a .jtd file with OpenOffice on my Mac.  I've read that it's possible to view these files using Open Office, but I haven't found any instructions on how to get them open.

Answer (score 0):

You can open .jtd files with open office but it requires an extension to convert.
 .jtd files are made by JustSystems-Ichitaro, this program does not use xml as it does not use plain text, but they produce another application called Ichitaro Arc
This can handle xml and with a plug-in OpenOffice can [open the jtd files](http://www.ehow.com/info_12073802_jtd-file-extensions.html)
If you go to the company website, it will need to be translated unless you Japanese is good,
 they have a free download which [converts to xml (i think).](http://www.justsystems.com/jp/download/viewer/ichitaro/)
Some articles i read,(dated 2010) stated that it was only available to windows and linux, but
the wiki link states that they have had a [mac version for sometime.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ichitaro)
I could not find the mentioned OpenOffice [extension](http://extensions.services.openoffice.org/en/getmore?cid=920794)
It will be there but my searches returned no extensions that matched.
I hope this helps in someway.